# How from an array of objects to map the data in a new object based on a latest timestamp

Tags: javascript

I have the following snippet whose functionality is to re-map the mocked data in a new one, with new fields and a total calculation.

For simplicity was used a short array and one date.

The calculation is about how many Ids a status has and that gives the total.

From the OBJ you see `statusType` and what I need is to aggregate same status, studyId, label, siteId in one object and print out the total of Ids that statusType has.

The snippet calculates that but wrongly

```js
const mockData = [{
    id: "C10-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-05T01:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: "2020-12-05T02:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: "C10-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "DROPOUT_PRESCREENER",
    eligible: true,
    statusFrom: "2020-12-05T02:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: "2020-12-05T03:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: "C10-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-05T03:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: null
  }
];

function endOfDay(time) {
  const date = new Date(time);
  date.setUTCHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
  return date;
}

const assignLabel = (statusType, eligible) => {
  if (statusType === "INCOMPLETE") return "pending";
  if (statusType === "REJECTED_PRESCREENER") return "ineligible";
  if (statusType === "DROPOUT_PRESCREENER" && eligible) return "eligible";
  if (statusType === "DROPOUT_PRESCREENER" && !eligible) return "abandoned";
  return "completed";
};

// This dates are generated from a fuction bases on which dates range we need
// In this cas is just one day
const batches = ["2020-12-05T00:00:00.000Z"];

const screeningNumbersCalculations = () => {
  const results = [];

  batches.forEach((t) => {
    const matchingStatusesTime = mockData.filter((s) => {
      return (
        new Date(s.statusFrom) < endOfDay(t) &&
        (s.statusTo === null || new Date(t) <= new Date(s.statusTo))
      );
    });

    matchingStatusesTime.forEach((ms) => {
      const r = {
        days: [t],
        studyId: ms.studyId,
        siteId: ms.siteId,
        screeningStage: "SELF_ASSESSMENT",
        label: assignLabel(ms.statusType, ms.eligible),
        total: 1
      };

      const key = `${r.days}${r.studyId}${r.siteId}${r.label}`;
      if (!results[key]) results[key] = r;
      else results[key].total += 1;
    });
  });

  return Object.values(results);
};

const screeningNumbers = screeningNumbersCalculations();

console.log(JSON.stringify(screeningNumbers, null, 2));
```

The result in the snippet is about 2 objects but the expected result should be as follow

```
{
          days: [ 2020-12-05T00:00:00.000Z ],
          studyId: 'TBX4',
          siteId: 'USA-1',
          screeningStage: 'SELF_ASSESSMENT',
          label: 'pending',
          total: 1
},
```

The reason is those objects have the same ID on the same day and what changes is the status. In this scenario, I should consider only the latest status which is also the current status, and not have calculated the other 2.

I don't know now how to do that in my implementation.

The goal is that I print for the same date all the statuses totals but I need to consider an ID can change the status on the same day so I have to calculate based on the last timestamp of `statusFrom`

Comment: Do you need to consider only one `id` in a day, the latest one ?

Comment: Practically yes one ID the latest one

Comment: What would be the output if obj with `DROPOUT_PRESCREENER` wasn't there ?

Comment: In the same day we only consider the latest status so the one `DROPOUT_PRESCREENER` will be not considered in class as it is now.
We should have in the scenario just one OBJ as I showed in my question

Comment: Whatever status we have the latest one is considered could be another status type like PENDING_CALLCENTER doesn't matter what matter is what is the latest for the same ID

Comment: If we don't have the DROPOUT the result will be the same actually as we have the same status for the same ID on the same ID so will be total = 1 still as it is like a duplicate.

Comment: What’s the type of values in `batches`, I see you are doing `new Date(t)` even though the value is of type Date

Comment: So the original output of batches is like this from the console `[2020-12-05T00:00:00.000Z]` I added a new Date() because the snippets were not working otherwise maybe I did something wrong

Comment: I changed and still working the date is a type of date by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can sort based on date then omit the duplicates by overwriting using an object, then evaluate on the result values of the object. Hope that suites your needs.

```js
const mockData = [{
    id: "C10-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-05T01:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: "2020-12-05T02:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: "C10-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "DROPOUT_PRESCREENER",
    eligible: true,
    statusFrom: "2020-12-05T02:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: "2020-12-05T03:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    id: "C10-TBX4",
    studyId: "TBX4",
    siteId: "USA-1",
    statusType: "INCOMPLETE",
    statusFrom: "2020-12-05T03:00:00.000Z",
    statusTo: null
  }
];

function endOfDay(time) {
  const date = new Date(time);
  date.setUTCHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
  return date;
}

const assignLabel = (statusType, eligible) => {
  if (statusType === "INCOMPLETE") return "pending";
  if (statusType === "REJECTED_PRESCREENER") return "ineligible";
  if (statusType === "DROPOUT_PRESCREENER" && eligible) return "eligible";
  if (statusType === "DROPOUT_PRESCREENER" && !eligible) return "abandoned";
  return "completed";
};

// This dates are generated from a fuction bases on which dates range we need
// In this cas is just one day
const batches = ["2020-12-05T00:00:00.000Z"];

const screeningNumbersCalculations = () => {
  const results = {}; // Dont use array since you are using it as dictionary Object.
  // Putting latest records at end so we can confidently overwrite with records of same day in next step
  mockData.sort((a, b) => endOfDay(a).getTime() - endOfDay(b).getTime());
  const dateidMap = mockData.reduce((accum, item) => {
    accum[`${endOfDay(item).getTime()}.${item.id}`] = item;
    return accum;
  }, {});

  batches.forEach(t => {
    // or filter matching times first and generate dateidMap later.
    const matchingStatusesTime = Object.values(dateidMap).filter((s) => {
      return (
        new Date(s.statusFrom) < endOfDay(t) &&
        (s.statusTo === null || new Date(t) <= new Date(s.statusTo))
      );
    });

    matchingStatusesTime.forEach((ms) => {
      const key = `${t}${ms.studyId}${ms.siteId}${assignLabel(ms.statusType, ms.eligible)}`;
      if (!results[key]) {
        results[key] = {
          days: [t],
          studyId: ms.studyId,
          siteId: ms.siteId,
          screeningStage: "SELF_ASSESSMENT",
          label: assignLabel(ms.statusType, ms.eligible),
          total: 0
        };
      }
      results[key].total++;
    });
  });
  return Object.values(results);
};
const screeningNumbers = screeningNumbersCalculations();

console.log(JSON.stringify(screeningNumbers, null, 2));
```

Comment: Will give a try and see if that is good for my needs

Comment: I finally was able to try it but in my project, I have a lint restriction and cannot use _fromDateTime can you edit to not use the _ please

Comment: I have a last question just to learn better. Can you explain me better what this does? 
`const dateidMap = mockData.reduce((accum, item) => {
    accum[`${endOfDay(item).getTime()}.${item.id}`] = item;
    return accum;
  }, {});`

Comment: There is one more thing after I tested when I do the console log of the `dateIdMap` I see `NaN.something` should not be an identifier in front instead of NaN?

Comment: If you are getting `NAN.something`, means your date value is wrong